# Get one of the two random variables's distribution function from limitation

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables

This is a very fundamental problem. In the Stochastic Processes textbook, it says that:

> The Continuity Theorem of Probability allows us to conclude that
>   $$F_X(x)=\lim_{y \to \infty}F_{XY}(x,y)$$

I know it's right but don't know why, I'm confused, so..can someone gives me a proof mathematically?

The problem posing here is that, actually the $(\{X\leq x\},\{Y\leq y\})$ stands for  the Cartesian product of $\{X\leq x\}\times\{Y\leq y\}$ on $R^2$. We have no information about $P_{xy}$ even though we know everything about $X$ and $Y$. Hence we cannot simply say $P(X\leq x,S) = P(X\leq x)$, then how can we get the above equation?

Comment: what exactly is the confusion ?

Comment: @TrafalgarLaw The equation, we don't have the information of how the two r.v. are combined, then how can we deduce this equation whatever the two r.v. look like?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\Pr(X\le x) & = \Pr(X\le x\ \&\ (Y\le0\text{ or }0<Y\le1\text{ or }1<Y\le2 \text{ or } 2<Y\le3 \text{ or }\ldots)) \\[8pt]
& = \Pr(X\le x\ \&\ Y\le0)+\Pr(X\le x\ \&\ 0<Y\le1)+\Pr(X\le x\ \&\ 1<Y\le2)+\cdots \\[8pt]
& = \lim_{n\to\infty} \Pr(X\le x\ \&\ Y\le0)+\cdots\cdots+\Pr(X\le x\ \&\ n<Y\le n+1) \\[8pt]
& = \lim_{n\to\infty} F(x,n+1).
\end{align}
$$

Instead of a sequence whose $n$th term is $n+1$, you can use any other sequence that increases to $\infty$, and hence the limit is the same as $\lim_{y\to\infty} F(x,y)$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that for every nondecreasing sequence $(A_n)$ of events of union $A=\bigcup\limits_nA_n$, one has $$P[A]=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}P[A_n].
$$
Apply this to $A_n=[X\leqslant x,Y\leqslant y_n]$ where the sequence $(y_n)$ is nondecreasing and with limit $+\infty$, then $A=[X\leqslant x]$ hence $$P[X\leqslant x]=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}P[X\leqslant x,Y\leqslant y_n],$$ that is, $$F_X(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}F_{X,Y}(x,y_n).$$ This applies to every nondecreasing sequence $(y_n)$ with limit $+\infty$ hence $$F_X(x)=\lim\limits_{y\to+\infty}F_{X,Y}(x,y).$$

Answer (score 0):

In probability theory $f_X(x)$ denotes PDF (Probability Density Function) and $F_X(X)$ denotes the CDF ( Cumulative Distribution Function ) .

If you are given the $f_X(x)$ you can calculate $F_X(x)$ which is equivalent to $P(X\le x)$ ie $$F_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x}f_X(x)dx$$

This is all the background you need to know to deal with this theorem .

$$F_{X}\left(x\right) = P(X \leq x) = P\left(X \leq x, Y < \infty\right) = \lim_{y \rightarrow \infty}P\left(\left\{X \leq x, Y \leq y\right\}\right) = \lim_{y \rightarrow \infty}F_{XY}\left(x,y\right)$$

Comment: Not every random variable has a density.  The last line you wrote is a correct proof though.

Comment: @Chris Janjigian I didn't know that every random variable had a density . I will ask two things (1)Please give an example where random variable doesn't have a density (2) If they have a density then what I have written is correct , isn't it ?

Comment: No discrete random variable has a density (Bernoulli, geometric, Poisson, negative binomial, etc.).  The Cantor distribution is continuous and does not have a density.  If the random variable has a density then what you have written is correct, yes.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian Okay I understand what you are saying but given the premise that if $F_Y(y)$ is discrete function then instead of integration we will have a summation over y from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ and even then this statement hold correct , right ?

Comment: In the discrete case, if you want to think of it as a sum with respect to the pmf then you can make a similar argument, yes.  Such a function does not have a PDF though.  In any event, there are continuous random variables with no density (like the Cantor distribution).

Comment: Maybe this example will help illustrate the issue.  Call $X$ a standard normal random variable and $Y$ an independent Bernoulli$(\frac{1}{2})$ random variable.  Then $Z = XY$ is neither continuous nor discrete and has neither a pmf nor a PDF.  To see this, condition on $Y$.  With probability $\frac{1}{2}$, this random variable is $0$ and with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ it is conditionally normal.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian I think in the book which this person is asking from . I think they are talking about continuous processes .

Comment: "PDF" stands for "probability density function", not "probability distribution function".

Comment: how can we deduce the P(X≤x)=P(X≤x,Y<∞)?

Comment: @Gizak Dont take it the wrong way but study it once more thoroughly through book you will understand it . Even after that if there is a doubt you can look at Michael Hardy and my answer then .

Comment: @TrafalgarLaw Yeah you are right, I am a engineer, better leave the theoretical problems to the science student.